# Why can't django load multiple pages simultaneously?

Tags: python, django, load, simultaneous

I have a django aplication with an admin panel. When i add some item (it takes about 10 seconds to add it), i can't load any other page. The page is waiting for the first page to load, and then it load itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using the development server? It's single-threaded by design. You'll need to run your Django app in a real web server (like Apache) to load pages simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, i'm using the development server. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2):

As Bob points out, the devserver/runserver is single-threaded, but if you want to, there is a [multi-threaded local dev server option](http://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver)